# A postfix real time incoming mail review system for spam, with reject option?

Tags: email, postfix, spam

Would it be possible to monitor my email account traffic on postfix and "intercept" incoming mail at the delivery stage, read the subject and attachment file names and have the option to manually reject its delivery with a mail failed delivery code, so that my address might be taken off the spam list as perceived to be not working anymore ?

Comment: Spammers never take email addresses off their lists. There's no reason for them to do so.

Comment: Potentially there is, as often mailer services will monitor rejections/bounces, and if the rate is too high suspend account on suspicion of spam